# Как изменить сортировку на 1 единицу меньше в блокноте?

Tags: сортировка

Есть файл kml там находятся различные метки. У каждой метки есть наименование и нумерация. Бывает такое что 1 метки не хватает и нумерация сбивается. Например: 55,56,57,...,59,60,61. Нужно сделать так чтобы последующие числа в наименованиях меток стали на 1 единицу меньше(т.е 59,60,61 поменялись на 58,59,60). Каким образом можно это сделать и есть ли в каких нибудь текстовых редакторах такая возможность?

Comment: Получается, что нужно использовать не то число, которое там записано, а просто считать количество записей и ставить порядковый номер

Comment: Эти метки делаются людьми. Они могут пропустить одну метку и все последующие метки нужно будет поменять на 1 единицу назад

Comment: Эти метки делаются людьми. Они могут пропустить одну метку и все последующие метки нужно будет поменять на 1 единицу назад

Comment: Ну вот я и предложил - не использовать эти метки вообще, а ввести свои, основанные на счётчике записей.